# retrieving textbox data to sql from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

i have a code to move data from asp.net (c# code) to sql. In the following code i have inserted  values directly (i.e) xxx and yyy.This works too. Now i want to insert the values which was entered in text boxes. What will be the code to do so?. Help  me friends.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    string  comm="insert into login values('xxx','yyy')";
    con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString.ToString();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(comm, con);
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    con.Open();
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Connection.Close();  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
     string  comm="insert into login values(@val1,@val2)";         
    con = new SqlConnection();         
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString.ToString();         
    cmd = new SqlCommand(comm, con);         
    cmd.Connection.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@val1",TextBox1.Text); //Replace TextBox1.Text with your first textbox
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@val2",TextBox2.Text); //Replace TextBox2.Text with your second textbox         

    con.Open();         
    int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();         
    cmd.Connection.Close();      
}
```

Comment: also, i tried with "insert into login values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "')";

Comment: @anvisha Pleasure, please don't use: ('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "') as that opens it up to sql injection which isn't good, a quick google will show you why. Please also remember to mark as correct.